# GAE datastore composite filter not working

Tags: google-cloud-datastore

I am constructing a composite filter, It has OR and then AND filter operator when I set the sort order to this query it is not giving the correct result.

the query that I am trying to execute is { status == Initiated OR (Status == Failed AND failedCount <= 5 ) }. it actually executing the query without any error but the result is not exactly the correct. it retrieving only "status == failed AND failedCount <= 5 " not the status == initiated. and the order I need is "createdAt" field.

```
Filter initiatedFilter = new FilterPredicate("status", FilterOperator.EQUAL, "Initiated");

Filter failedFilter = new FilterPredicate("status", FilterOperator.EQUAL, "Failed");

Filter failedCountFilter = new FilterPredicate("failedCount", FilterOperator.LESS_THAN_OR_EQUAL, 5);

CompositeFilter failedCompositeFilter = CompositeFilterOperator.and(failedFilter, failedCountFilter);

CompositeFilter initaiedFailedFilter = CompositeFilterOperator.or(initiatedFilter, failedCompositeFilter);

Query query2 = new Query("JobInstance").setFilter(initaiedFailedFilter).addSort("failedCount", SortDirection.ASCENDING).addSort("createdAt", SortDirection.ASCENDING);

jobEntitesList = datastoreService.prepare(query2).asList(FetchOptions.Builder.withLimit(limit));

for (Entity jobEntity2 : jobEntitesList) {
    /* doing some task */
}
```

What I have observed is If a remove the addSort() its working fine. but for me sort is important. I want the result should be in "createdAt" order. If I remove failedCount then it is throwing some error.

Answer (score 1):

Or filters are implemented entirely in the client (like IN query filters: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/datastore/queries#filters).  So your sort is happening in the client.  It's likely that you are getting all of the results from the `status == Failed AND FailedCount <= 5` query before getting any results from the `status == Initiated`.

From your comment, it's unclear what sort order you are looking for.  As documented in the [Restrictions on queries](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/datastore/query-restrictions#properties_used_in_inequality_filters_must_be_sorted_first), the primary sort order must be on failedCount since that has an inequality filter.

Comment: Thank you, Jim. because the query has inequality filter I have to use "failedCount" as primary sort then another sort is "createdAt". you can see in the code section. What doubt I have is if I remove both sorts it is giving the correct result without sorting but for me sorting is required. why two behavior I'm not clear? If I use IN operator can this give a correct result?